# c# InkStrokeBuilder loss of data

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp

I have a drawing project where a user can create drawings, back it up to a server and use elsewhere (on other platforms)

To achieve this, I can only back up drawings in a Collection of Points scheme, using the following object.

```
public class Drawing
{
    public Drawing()
    {
        points = new List<List<int>>();
    }
    public List<List<int>> points { get; set; }
    public string colour { get; set; }
}
```

I use the c# Inkmanager to help me draw sketches. To save, I extract the strokes and save them as a list of points, as follows.

```
private List<Drawing> GetDrawingsFromInkManager()
    {
        List<Drawing> returnList = new List<Drawing>();
        var strokes = m_InkManager.GetStrokes();

        int scount = 1;

        foreach (var s in strokes)
        {
            var renderingStrokes = s.GetRenderingSegments();

            Drawing drawing = new Drawing() { colour = m_CurrentDrawingColor.ToString() };

            foreach (var rs in renderingStrokes)
            {
                drawing.points.Add(new List<int>() { (int)rs.Position.X, (int)rs.Position.Y });
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Drawing: " + scount++ + " points added: " + drawing.points.Count + " RenderSegmentsCount: " + renderingStrokes.Count);

            returnList.Add(drawing);

        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

result output is:

> Drawing: 1 points added: 33 RenderSegmentsCount: 33
>
> Drawing: 2 points added: 22 RenderSegmentsCount: 22
>
> Drawing: 3 points added: 21 RenderSegmentsCount: 21

During this process, bezier curve data is lost, which for now should not be concern, as a set of straight segments is acceptable (the points only vary by 1-2 pixels).

When restoring points, I use the c# StrokeBuilder class and pass it a list of points. However, the resulting stroke only has half the strokes.

```
private void RestoreSegmentFromList(List<Point> pointList)
    {
        var color = m_CurrentMode == "Ink" ? m_CurrentDrawingColor : m_CurrentHighlightColor;
        var size = m_CurrentMode == "Ink" ? m_CurrentDrawingSize : m_CurrentHighlightSize;

        InkStrokeBuilder isBuiler = new InkStrokeBuilder();
        var points = pointList.Select(x => new Point(x.X* sketchScale, x.Y*sketchScale)).ToList();

        var inkStroke = isBuiler.CreateStroke(points);
        m_InkManager.AddStroke(inkStroke);

        Debug.WriteLine("Restoring; points added: " + points.Count + " RenderSegmentsCount: " + inkStroke.GetRenderingSegments().Count);

    }
```

> Restoring; points added: 33 RenderSegmentsCount: 16
>
> Restoring; points added: 22 RenderSegmentsCount: 14
>
> Restoring; points added: 21 RenderSegmentsCount: 12

**My question**, is this the intended behaviour of the strokebuilder class? The way I understand strokes is that they consist of one position and two bezier control points. The position is always the endpoint of a particular segment of the stroke, with the end-point of the previous segment being the start of the current one. But as far as I'm aware my methods above use the same manner to extract as to create. Surely then if I get X number of rendering segments from an inkManager I should be able to restore said X number, using only a set of points. Am I using the CreateStroke() method wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> To save, I extract the strokes and save them as a list of points.

Why you do this, you can simply save all `InkStroke` objects to the specified stream using [InkStrokeContainer.SaveAsync | saveAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkStrokeContainer.SaveAsync);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true). There is a official [Simple inking sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleInk), in scenario 3, drawings can be saved to files and loaded from files. If you don't want to save it locally, you can just create a `InMemoryRandomAccessStream`, and upload this stream. For example:

```
using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(stream);

    //TODO: Upload this stream.
}
```

And when you want to load this `InkStroke` on other platforms, you can download it as stream and:

```
await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.LoadAsync(stream);
```

This might not be the perfect answer to your data-lost issue, but I think this is how Strokes correctly be saved and loaded and it is much simpler.

Comment: The reason I need the points is because of cross-platform support. The drawings need to render on Android and IOS as well, so I can't use the InkStrokeContainer.SaveAsync method as the data saved is incompatible with other platforms.

Comment: @nicovanvuuren, I think no matter on what platform, the hanling with stream should be the similar, cause it actually generate a stream for uploading, so you mean in android and ios, there are no way to load strokes from stream? Can they load from file? If can, stream should work here.